# Clearing a map with a pointer value in Go

Tags: dictionary, garbage-collection, go

I have a map[string]*list.List and each list node is a pointer too. By simply clearing the map to nil, will all the map and list and all those pointers be cleared and garbage collected and ready to use again?

```
type UnrolledGroup struct {                                                                                                                                          
    next int
    s    []uint32
 }

 var dictionary = struct {
     m    map[string]*list.List
     keys []string                                                                                                                                                    
 }{m: make(map[string]*list.List)}

 l := list.New()
 newGroup := UnrolledGroup{next: 1, s: make([]uint32, groupLen)}
 newGroup.s[0] = pos
 l.PushBack(&newGroup)
 dictionary.m[token] = l
```

Now does this clear the whole thing?

```
 dictionary.m = nil
```

Comment: quite similar question here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/6NxgkyQxS2c

Comment: The garbage collector will eventually remove the object from memory. There's no guarantee when this is going to happen though.

Answer (score 3):

That depends: Everything is GC'ed if it is no longer "reachable".  If you keep other references to the stuff you store in the map it won't be collected. If the map is the sole root to these objects they will get collected. (Don't think too much about such stuff.)

Comment: I was going to say the same thing, and even if you *are* sure you've got no references left lying around, and you're *still* really paranoid, you *can* use `runtime.GC()` (http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GC), but it's probably going to be detrimental if you don't *really* know what else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

`map` is a reference type, i.e. it is a pointer type to an underlying structure. You may set your pointer to `nil`, but if someone else has a pointer to the same underlying structure, then they still have a reference to all the things inside.